# Lazy loading child list within a BusinessObject

Tags: architecture, lazy-loading, n-tier-architecture

I am using a 3-layer (UI, BLL, DAL) architecture and use BusinessObjects (aka Data Transfer Objects - DTO) between these layers. Suppose I have the following DTOs:

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmailDTO> EmailList { get; set; }
}

public class EmailDTO
{
    public int EmailID { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I want to lazyload the EmailList collection when I use the EmployeeDTO since it can be alot of data. So basically the EmployeeDTO will be created at the DAL level (without Email collection) and sent back to the UI via BLL. At this point how can I lazyload the EmailList at the UI Level. My code (omitting details) is similar to the following:

### UI

```
{
    EmployeeDTO empDTO = new EmployeeBLL().GetEmployeeByID (id);
}
```

### BLL

```
public EmployeeDTO GetEmployeeByID (id)
{
    return new EmployeeDAL().GetEmployeeByID (id);
}
```

### DAL

```
public EmployeeDTO GetEmployeeByID (id)
{
    reader = get employee data by id...

    EmployeeDTO empDTO = new EmployeeDTO ();
    empDTO.EmpID = reader [1];
    empDTO.Name  = reader [2];
    // I can load the email list but i dont
    return empDTO;
}
```

Now at the DAL level when I use **empDTO.EmailList ()**, it should lazy load the data.  How can i do so. I need a clean solution (please note I am not using any ORM). Thanks.

Comment: Your employee DTO might need some kind of callback that will fetch the next set of records.

Answer (score 2):

First - declare emails as virtual:

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmailDTO> EmailList { get; set; }
}
```

Next - create class, which inherits from `EmployeeDTO` and provides lazy-loading functionality:

```
public class LazyEmployeeDTO : EmployeeDTO
{
    public override ICollection<EmailDTO> EmailList
    {
        get 
        {
            if (base.EmailList == null)
               base.EmailList = LoadEmails();

            return base.EmailList;
        }

        set { base.EmailList = value; }
    }

    private ICollection<EmailDTO> LoadEmails()
    {
        var emails = new List<EmailDTO>();
        // get emails by EmpID from database
        return emails;            
    }
}
```

And last - return `LazyEmployeeDTO` from DAL, but make sure that client depend on simple `EmployeeDTO`:

```
public EmployeeDTO GetEmployeeByID (id)
{
    reader = get employee data by id...

    EmployeeDTO empDTO = new LazyEmployeeDTO();
    empDTO.EmpID = reader[1];
    empDTO.Name  = reader[2];
    // do not load emails
    return empDTO;
}
```

Rest of code should stay as is. This lazy employee will act as proxy for base employee, and clients will not know that they are not using `EmployeeDTO`.

Comment: thanks for replying. This clarify things quite a bit but a few more question (sorry I am novice to this concept so please bear with my questions). 1) How do we pass the **id** when calling the code 'EmployeDTO empDTO = new LazyEmployeeDTO();'. 2) What do you mean by **return LazyEmployeeDTO from DAL**. 3) From the UI, how do we actually call the EmailList collection. 4). In this case, we have one child collection. If we have n child collections then do we have to create n inherited classes. Appreciate your response.

Comment: 1) you do not need to pass id. Keep it as is - `empDTO.EmpID = reader.GetInt32(0)` 2) see last code block - `LazyEmployeeDTO` instance is created, but assigned to `EmployeeDTO` variable. Also method returns `EmployeeDTO` type. 3) Same way as you did it with `EmployeeDTO` class 4) No, if you have N child collections, than you override all these collections in single `LazyEmployeeDTO` class.